# PHP MYSQL RSS FEED limit issues

Tags: php, mysql, rss, feed

I am trying to put together an RSS feed from a MYsql data base. but the script will only post 2 events. if LIMIT set to 3 or more, it comes up with the error message:

```
This page contains the following errors:
error on line 26 at column 29: xmlParseEntityRef: no name
```

Below is a rendering of the page up to the first error. This is my code:

```
<?php
header('Content-Type: text/xml');
mysql_connect("localhost", "username", "password") or die(mysql_error());
mysql_select_db("database") or die(mysql_error());

echo '<?xml version="1.0" encoding="ISO-8859-1"?>
<rss version="2.0">
<channel>
<title>My Website Name</title>
<description>A description of the feed</description>
<link>The URL to the website</link>';

$get_articles = "SELECT id, title, description,
DATE_FORMAT(start_date,'%a, %e %b %Y %T') as formatted_date
FROM table_name ORDER BY start_date DESC LIMIT 4";

$articles = mysql_query($get_articles) or die(mysql_error());

while ($article = mysql_fetch_array($articles)){

echo '
   <item>
      <title>'.$article[title].'</title>
      <description><![CDATA[
      '.$article[description].'
      ]]></description>
      <link>http://www.gigreview.com.au/index.php/gig-review/'.$article[id].'</link>
      <pubDate>'.$row[formatted_date].' GMT</pubDate>
  </item>';
}
echo '</channel>
</rss>';
?>
```

Answer (score 0):

Try to validate the XML through http://validator.w3.org/feed/ - Maybe its signs like & that needs to be & - You could try with: http://php.net/manual/en/function.htmlspecialchars.php